# SQL nesting on highschool test

Tags: sql

We made this test on my school, and according to the test this is the right answer:

```
SELECT 
    names 
FROM 
    COMPANY 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
                    kgmilk 
                FROM 
                    COWS 
                WHERE kgmilk < 1000 AND COMPANY.nr = COWS.nr)
```

Now my question is, can you actually do `COMPANY.nr = COWS.nr` in the nested query, since you only select one database in that query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which kind of SQL this is.

If it's MS SQL Server, `COMPANY.nr = COWS.nr` is possible.

See [this example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184297.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) and it will in effect get evaluated for each row in the main table (ignoring optimization).

Answer (score 0):

The nested query - commonly called a subquery - is a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), which means that it is evaluated for each row in the outer query. The correlation occurs when, within the subquery, you reference a table in the outer query. Here's an example of a plain subquery:

```
select
 NAME
from
 COMPANY
where
 NAME not in (
  select 
   NAME
  from
   COMPANY_BLACKLIST
 )
```